# UINavigationController change InteractivePopGesture direction

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I am designing a right to left application.I've made everything rtl by using this line of code:

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

and that works correct for everything expect the interactive pop gesture of my navigation controller.
the direction of the segue is correct:

[image]

but when I want to use the pop gesture (swipe from left edge to right edge) the view become visible from opposite side.
How should I change it? 
I've tried changing the edges to .right but that disabled the gesture recognizer :

```
let gesture = interactivePopGestureRecognizer as! UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer
    gesture.edges = .right
```

Comment: now your problem is with UINavigationController that when you swipe from left to right you want present the sideMenu but it goes back to past viewController, am I right ?

Comment: سلام.نه مشکلم اینه که وقتی صفحه رو‌از چپ میکشم راست اون @arashترنزیشنی که انجام میشه برعکسشه.یعنی من از چپ به راست میکشم این صفحه بالایی از راست به چپ حرکت میکنه.دقیقا تو اسنپ صفحه پروفایلش این رو درستش رو پیاده کرده از راست میکشی به چپ صفحه هم تو همون جهت حرکت میکنه ولی مال من جهت حرکت صفحم درسته جهت اون سوایپ جسچر برعکسه

Comment: do you use any GitHub library ?

Comment: no i use uinavigationController and the gesture is the default pop gesture wich is implemented in that class.@arash

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should change the both `view` and `navigationBar` semantic attribute
use this extension:

```
extension UIViewController {
    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        navigationController?.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        navigationController?.navigationBar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do this for only one view controller instead of all the view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me using `UINavigationController` instead of `UIViewController`:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        navigationController?.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        navigationController?.navigationBar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    }
}
```